# Use JavaScript to Change an Input Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box that shows the quantity of an item to be ordered.  I it is left blank I want it to be zero, not blank.
**JavaScript**

```
$('.itemQty').on('change',function(){
    var qty = this;
    if( qty.var() === "" ){
        qty.var( "0" );
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="itemQty">
```

This is not working, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `qty.var()` should be `qty.val()`.  Also you need to create a jQuery object: `var qty = $(this);`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Perfect!  I hate stupid mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typo

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
if( qty.val() === "" ){
       //^^
```

---

http://learn.jquery.com

http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Really?!  Stupid typo?!  I've been trying variations for 30 minutes!

Comment: @Andrew Never mind . Learn more with links mentioned in the answer.